# Force refresh cached index.html file in Node express

Tags: node.js, express, caching

**What is the best way to make sure all users get a fresh index.html instead of cached index.html?**

So last week I tried to make the user cache the js and css bundles for a Single page application. I did it adding max age in the server.js file:

```
app.use(express.static('build', { maxAge: '365d' }));
```

The problem is that the index.html file is also in the build folder. Which means that it`s being cached client side for 365 days...

So even though I have cache busting on the js and css bundles, the index.html file is always the same and therefore the bundles stays the same because of the old hash.

I have now changed the server to use Etag instead:

```
app.use(express.static('build', { etag: true }));
```

This works great.

The problem is that i pushed this to production and now all the users have an stale index.html.

I use Node express and AWS Application Load balancer.

The endpoint which sends the index.html looks like this:

```
app.get('*', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build/index.html'));
});
```

Does anyone have a smart solution?

I have looked into using a php file like this: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1910 . Is that the best solution?

Comment: Ever found a solution? Just hit the same scenario...

Comment: This brings back bad memories. Sorry. I tried a lot of stuff. As long as the client hit the server or load balancer it should be possible, but I couldnt figure it out. Good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a related problem where, after a deployment, users would need to hard refresh in certain browsers. It was due to blindly caching all build files, including the index.html.

Here's how we resolved it:

```js
app
.use(express.static(BUILD, {
  maxAge: '30 days',
  setHeaders: (res, path) => {
    if (express.static.mime.lookup(path) === 'text/html') {
      // Skip cache on html to load new builds.
      res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    }
  }
}))
.get('/*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(HTML));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send header no-cache when using index.html route

For example:

```
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
  response.header('Expires', '-1');
  response.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: This would have worked if the users didn't already have a copy of index.html. But since they av copy which says that it`s good for 365 days it never hits the server